# Using Scala 2.10 reflection how can I list the values of Enumeration?

Tags: scala, reflection, enumeration, scala-2.10

Having a following enumeration

```
object ResponseType extends Enumeration {
  val Listing, Album = Value
}
```

How do I get a list of its vals?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to be thorough about this, you need to check that your symbols have `Value` as a supertype:

```
def valueSymbols[E <: Enumeration: TypeTag] = {
  val valueType = typeOf[E#Value]
  typeOf[E].members.filter(sym => !sym.isMethod &&
    sym.typeSignature.baseType(valueType.typeSymbol) =:= valueType
  )
}
```

Now even if you have the following (which is perfectly legal):

```
object ResponseType extends Enumeration {
  val Listing, Album = Value
  val someNonValueThing = "You don't want this in your list of value symbols!"
}
```

You still get the correct answer:

```
scala> valueSymbols[ResponseType.type] foreach println
value Album
value Listing
```

Your current approach would include `value someNonValueThing` here.

Comment: Quite reasonable indeed. Thanks

Comment: Note that type aliases of `Enumeration#Value` match the above filter predicate.  To get around this, also check `! sym.isType`.

Answer (score 7):

The following code gets a list of `Symbol` objects representing the "vals":

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._ // Access the reflection api

typeOf[ResponseType.Value]  //  - A `Type`, the basic unit of reflection api
  .asInstanceOf[TypeRef]    //  - A specific kind of Type with knowledge of
                            //    the place it's being referred from
  .pre                      //  - AFAIK the referring Type
  .members                  //  - A list of `Symbol` objects representing
                            //    all members of this type, including 
                            //    private and inherited ones, classes and 
                            //    objects - everything.
                            //    `Symbol`s are the second basic unit of 
                            //    reflection api.
  .view                     //  - For lazy filtering
  .filter(_.isTerm)         //  - Leave only the symbols which extend the  
                            //    `TermSymbol` type. This is a very broad 
                            //    category of symbols, which besides values
                            //    includes methods, classes and even 
                            //    packages.
  .filterNot(_.isMethod)    //  - filter out the rest
  .filterNot(_.isModule)
  .filterNot(_.isClass)
  .toList                   //  - force the view into a final List
```

It should be noted that instead of filtering on is-clauses it can be implemented with `.collect` testing for specific types, like so:

```
.collect{ case symbol : MethodSymbol => symbol }
```

This approach may be required for other tasks in the reflection api.

It also should be noted, that using a `.view` is not mandatory at all, it just makes using a series of `filter` applications (as much as many other functions such as `map`, `flatMap` and etc.) much more effective, by traversing the input collection only once and at the point where it's actually being forced into some concrete collection (`.toList` in our case).

### Update

As suggested by Travis Brown, it is also possible to reference the `ResponseType` object directly. So the `typeOf[ResponseType.Value].asInstanceOf[TypeRef].pre` part can be replaced with  `typeOf[ResponseType.type]`

Comment: Why not just use `typeOf[ResponseType.type].members...`? Without some discussion of motivation your constraints feel a little arbitrary.

Comment: @TravisBrown because these vals are not members of `typeOf[ResponseType.Value]`, that's the whole point

Comment: No, but they are members of `ResponseType`.

Comment: @TravisBrown Sorry. Didn't notice you had ResponseType **.type** there. This is obviously a nice solution. I've updated the answer to include it

Comment: There's still a potential problem with this approach—see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12133868/334519).

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over the values of an enumeration via the set returned by the
enumeration’s values method:

```
scala> for (e <- ResponseType.values) println(e)
Listing
Album
```

Comment: I'm sorry but the question was about using reflection.