# Scala class that handles enumerations generically

Tags: scala, generics, types, parameters, enums

I want to create a generic class that holds the value of an enumeration, and also allows access to the possible values of the enumeration. Think of a property editor for example - you need to know the current value of the property, and you also need to be able to know what other values are legal for the property. And the type of enumeration should not be known in advance, you should be able to work with any kind of enumeration.

My first thought was something like this:

```
class EnumerationProperty[T <: Enumeration](value:T)
```

However, that doesn't work because for enumerations T isn't a type, it's an object. Other variations I have tried are:

```
class EnumerationProperty[T <: Enumeration](value:T.Value)
class EnumerationProperty[T <: Enumeration.Value](value:T)
```

(I won't go into the details of why these don't work because I suspect the reasons aren't interesting.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your use case (a property editor) I think the best solution is to rely on scala reflection available in scala 2.10. Given a class's `TypeTag`, you can get the full type (without erasure) of all of its members plus their values, and from that populate your property editor. For enumerations, use the `TypeTag` to get their values using the following method:
[Using Scala 2.10 reflection how can I list the values of Enumeration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129172/using-scala-2-10-reflection-how-can-i-list-the-values-of-enumeration)

---

Now, maybe you don't want or can't use scala reflection, and from now on I'll suppose this is the case. If that is true then you are opening a whole can of worm :)
**TL;DR:** This is not possible using a standard `Enumeration`, so you'll probably have to explcitly wrap the enumeration values as shown in Ptharien's Flame's answer (or roll your own fork of `Enumeration`). Below I detail all my attempts, please bear with me.

Unfortunately, and for some unknown reason  to me (though I suspect it has to do with serialization issues), `Enumeration.Value` has no field pointing to its `Enumeration` instance. Given how `Enumeration` is implemented, this would be trivial to implement, but of course wehave no say, short of forking Enumeration and modifying our version (which is actually what I did for this very purpose, plus to add proper support for serialization and reflection - but I diggress).

If we can't modify `Enumeration`, maybe we can just extend it? Looking at the implementation again, something like this would seem to work:

```
class EnumerationEx extends Enumeration {
  protected class ValEx(i: Int, name: String) extends Val(i, name) {
    @transient val enum: Enumeration = EnumerationEx.this
  }
  override protected def Value(i: Int, name: String): Value = new ValEx(i, name)  
}

object Colors extends EnumerationEx {
  val Red, Green, Blue = Value
}
```

The downside would be that it only works for enumerations that explicitly extend `EnumerationEx` instead of `Enumeration`, but it would be better than nothing.

Unfortunately, this does not compile simply because `def Value ...` is declared final in `Enumeration` so there is no way to override it. (Note again that forking `Enumeration` would allow to circunvent this. Actually, why not do it, as we are already down the path of using a custom Enumeration anwyay. I'll let you judge).

So here is another take on it:

```
class EnumerationEx extends Enumeration {
  class ValueWithEnum( inner: Value ) {
    @transient val enum: Enumeration = EnumerationEx.this
  }
  implicit def valueToValue( value: Value ): ValueWithEnum = new ValueWithEnum( value )
}
```

And indeed **it works** as expected. Or so it seems.

```
scala> object Colors extends EnumerationEx {
     |   val Red, Green, Blue = Value
     | }
defined module Colors

scala> val red = Colors.Red
red: Colors.Value = Red

scala> red.enum.values
res58: Enumeration#ValueSet = Colors.ValueSet(Red, Green, Blue)
```

Hooray? Well no, because the conversion from `Value` to `ValueWithEnum` is done only when accessing `red.enum`, not at the time of instantiation of the `Colors` enumeration. In other words, when calling `enum` the compiler needs to know the exact static type of the enumeration (the compiler must statically know that red's type is `Colors.Value`, and not just `Enumeration# Value`). And in the use case you mention (a property editor) you can only rely to java reflection (I already assumed that you won't use scala reflection) to get the type of an enumeration value, and java reflection will only give you `Enumeration#Val` (which extends `Enumeration#Value`) as the type of `Colors.Red`. So basically you are stuck here.
Your best bet is definitly to use scala reflection in the first place.

Comment: In this case I'm OK with either using Scala reflection or subclassing Enumeration - happily in this case, I'm only interested in editing properties of Scala objects, not Java ones. It sounds like reflection is the better way to go here, although I'll need to check my scala version.

Answer (score 5):

For first part of your question. You can define holder for generic enum value like this:

```
case class EnumerationProperty[T <: Enumeration#Value](value:T)
```

But I don't know how to get all enum values without explicitly pass Enumeration object. Enumeration has `values()` method to get all values. And Enumeration#Value has link to Enumeration, but with private access

Answer (score 0):

```
class EnumProps[E <: Enumeration](val e: E)(init: e.Value) {...}
```

Then you can use `e` and `e.Value` to implement the class.