# Scala: how to convert enumeration to a map using reflection?

Tags: scala, reflection, enumeration

Is it possible to write a method like

```
def enumToMap[E <: Enumeration]: Map[String, Int]
```

that for a given enumeration, f.e.

```
object PROTOCOL_TYPE extends Enumeration{
  type PROTOCOL_TYPE = Value
  val HELLO = Value(0)
  val ERROR = Value(1)
  ...
}
```

will produce a map

```
Map("HELLO" -> 0, "ERROR" -> 1, ...)
```

I found a similar question:
[Using Scala 2.10 reflection how can I list the values of Enumeration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129172/using-scala-2-10-reflection-how-can-i-list-the-values-of-enumeration), but I cant grasp how to get integer id's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The main idea is to find companion object by value type. Here is my code:

```
def enumObjectForType[T <: Enumeration](implicit tt: TypeTag[T]) = {
  val universeMirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val objModule = typeOf[T].asInstanceOf[TypeRef].pre
                           .typeSymbol
                           .companionSymbol
                           .asModule
  val companionMirror = universeMirror.reflectModule(objModule)
  companionMirror.instance
}

def enumToMap[T <: Enumeration#Value](implicit tt: TypeTag[T]) = {
  val ett = tt.asInstanceOf[TypeTag[Enumeration]]
  val instance = enumObjectForType(ett).asInstanceOf[Enumeration]
  instance.values map { v => (v.toString, v.id)} toMap
}
```

Usage:

```
object PROTOCOL_TYPE extends Enumeration{
  type PROTOCOL_TYPE = Value
  val HELLO = Value(0)
  val ERROR = Value(1)
}

import PROTOCOL_TYPE._
println(enumToMap[PROTOCOL_TYPE]) // output is Map(HELLO -> 0, ERROR -> 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
def enumToMap[E <: Enumeration](e:E) = e.values.map { v => (v.toString,v.id) }.toMap
```

Note this approach does not use reflection.

Then

```
scala> enumToMap(PROTOCOL_TYPE)
res9: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(ERROR -> 1, HELLO -> 0)
```

**Update**

Another way to call `enumToMap`,

```
implicit def test[E <: Enumeration] (e:E) = new { def !() = enumToMap(e) }
```

Thus,

```
scala>  PROTOCOL_TYPE !
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(ERROR -> 1, HELLO -> 0)
```

This syntax, `!` , may be changed as desired to a more context related operator/symbol.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, temporally I use the same approach. But I have a third-party code that requires a method without parameters. The suggested approach breaks uniformity of code totally.

Comment: Added update on possible approach to invoking `enumToMap` without parameters. Hope this could help.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help, it is just a syntactic sugar. I really need a function from an enumeration type (maybe using implicit TypeTag and reflection) to a map.